# How to get the Thread response before page get rendered

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have an application which require File Operation , that need to be done as concurrently

1. If a user try to READ a file , other users cant perform WRITE operation
2. If a user try to WRITE to file , other user cant perform READ Operation

business logic applied :

Created  Thread using Runnable Interface and added Synchronized READ Methods  to read property file from remote location and put it into session /request object

- issue  : while starting a new thread the response get finished (since thread is independent path of execution) .so the property values are not available

How to get the thread response before the page  get  displayed ? I heared that we can use  Callable Interface , please share the best approach suited in this  situation.

Comment: Are you using spring or straight servlets?

Comment: am using pure Servlet , no frameworks

Comment: Can you share the code using the Runnable? I think you need to pass the response as parameter to the thread handle it, if I understood right. But it will be clearer if you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Making a thread in servlet in this way(initiate a `Runnable` and run it by JVM directly) is completely non-sense and not recommended for sake of memory leak, and unmanaged context.

It's completely nature you get undefined/nonstable states of request/session context by the new thread.

Since the thread gets started asynchronously, the servlet/server context continue its working and response to the client, and the request context is no more valid.

You may do it by a mutex, since the servlet context is multi-threaded by default, and you may not never and never run threads that way please, and if you do, you may do it by session context listeners to handle events and prevent any possible memory leak.

You may either wait(block) the response while the related context(file) is locked, which is not so logical. Or inform the user the requested file is being locked becasue of another read/write operation.
And of course you need a push like method(like websockets) or alternatives(check status by ajax or reloading) to check the latest related context status.

And the most logical way is, you need to do it in queue mode, and just make sure the part of the file need to be changed is valid with latest state.